# Convert strings matrix from Arduino to floats in Python

Tags: python, string, numbers

I have an Arduino, that give me the below values.
I can read this strings matrix in Python, but I need to convert this values to floats matrix.

```
['-0.4152832031\t0.1403808593\t-0.1831054687\t-1.0670732259\t-0.0609756088\t0.0000000000\t185\t-1\t-683\r\n']
['-0.4165039062\t0.1406250000\t-0.1867675781\t-0.8841463088\t0.1524390220\t-0.0304878044\t186\t-2\t-685\r\n']
['-0.4140625000\t0.1411132812\t-0.1843261718\t-0.8536585807\t0.4573170661\t-0.2743902444\t186\t-1\t-686\r\n']
['-0.4165039062\t0.1408691406\t-0.1870117187\t-1.0365853309\t0.0304878044\t-0.1219512224\t185\t-2\t-685\r\n']
['-0.4165039062\t0.1389160156\t-0.1857910156\t-1.0060975551\t0.0304878044\t0.0000000000\t183\t0\t-683\r\n']
['-0.4147949218\t0.1396484375\t-0.1862792968\t-0.9756097793\t0.0609756088\t0.0304878044\t184\t0\t-684\r\n']
['-0.4147949218\t0.1401367187\t-0.1872558593\t-1.0670732259\t0.1524390220\t-0.1219512224\t185\t-2\t-685\r\n']
['-0.4147949218\t0.1381835937\t-0.1862792968\t-0.9756097793\t0.0304878044\t-0.1829268360\t185\t0\t-683\r\n']
['-0.4135742187\t0.1391601562\t-0.1887207031\t-0.9756097793\t0.1219512224\t-0.1219512224\t184\t-1\t-684\r\n']
['-0.4160156250\t0.1394042968\t-0.1848144531\t-0.9146341323\t-0.0304878044\t0.0000000000\t184\t-2\t-685\r\n']
['-0.4167480468\t0.1384277343\t-0.1855468750\t-1.0975609970\t0.0304878044\t0.0914634132\t183\t-2\t-686\r\n']
['-0.4155273437\t0.1381835937\t-0.1860351562\t-0.8841463088\t0.0000000000\t-0.1524390220\t184\t-4\t-685\r\n']
['-0.4162597656\t0.1396484375\t-0.1845703125\t-0.9451219558\t0.1524390220\t-0.1524390220\t186\t-1\t-686\r\n']
['-0.4167480468\t0.1406250000\t-0.1870117187\t-1.0975609970\t0.0000000000\t0.0304878044\t184\t-2\t-684\r\n']
['-0.4162597656\t0.1369628906\t-0.1838378906\t-1.0060975551\t-0.0914634132\t-0.0304878044\t185\t-2\t-684\r\n']
['-0.4155273437\t0.1384277343\t-0.1865234375\t-1.4634146690\t0.0000000000\t0.1219512224\t185\t-1\t-683\r\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert your string to the list of `float` numbers, you may use a *list comprehension* expression with [**`str.split()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and type-cast each value to [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) as:

```
>>> num_str = '-0.4152832031\t0.1403808593\t-0.1831054687\t-1.0670732259\t-0.0609756088\t0.0000000000\t185\t-1\t-683\r\n'

>>> [float(n) for n in num_str.split()]
[-0.4152832031, 0.1403808593, -0.1831054687, -1.0670732259, -0.0609756088, 0.0, 185.0, -1.0, -683.0]
```

OR, you may use [**`map()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to get the same result as:

```
>>> map(float, num_str.split())
[-0.4152832031, 0.1403808593, -0.1831054687, -1.0670732259, -0.0609756088, 0.0, 185.0, -1.0, -683.0]
```

**Note:** `map()` returns generator object in Python 3.x. In order to convert it to list, you have to explicitly type-cast the value to `list` using `list(map(..., ...))`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I'm new in Python and some codes are new for me.